# Clean all the design changes when a window is closed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styles, local-storage

I have a dialog window (div) with a form in it and an object which holds the data from the fields, if the user forgets to fill one of the fields the border of this field becomes red. My problem is that if the user closes the dialog window and reopens it the red borders are still there and the object holds information from before the closing. I am not sure how/if I need to clear the local storage or if there is a better solution so every time the window is closed the data structure and styles are defaulted. I use Bootstrap for the components.

```
import React from 'react';

const variables = {
  varA: '', varB: '', varC: ''
};
let emptyFields = [];

const border = {
  borderColor: '#C70039',
};

const submitForm = () => {
  emptyFields = [];
  if (Object.values(variables).includes('')) {
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(variables)) {
      if (value === '') {
        emptyFields.push(key);
      }
    }
  }
  return emptyFields;
};

const Form = empty => (
  <div>
    <p className="text-primary">Please provide information in all of the fields.</p>
    <form>
      <div className="form-group mt-4" >
        <label htmlFor="formGroupExampleInput">Var A </label>
        <input type="text" className='form-control' id="varA" required onChange={(e) => { variables.varA = e.target.value; } } />
      </div>
      <div className="form-group">
        <label htmlFor="formGroupExampleInput">Var B </label>
        <input type="text" id="varB" className='form-control' style={empty.empty.includes('varB') ? border : null} onChange={(e) => { variables.varB = e.target.value; }}/>
      </div>
      <div className="form-group">
        <label htmlFor="formGroupExampleInput">Var C </label>
        <input type="text" className="form-control" id="varC" style={empty.empty.includes('varC') ? border : null} onChange={(e) => { variables.varC = e.target.value; }}/>
      </div>
    </form>
    <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={submitForm}>Submit</button>
  </div>
);

const CompleteForm = () => <Form empty = {emptyFields} />;

export default CompleteForm;
```

Comment: Could you add some code? A bug like this is down to your implementation. Also, how are you using react.js?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47240386/how-to-clear-data-in-textbox-in-reactjs

Comment: are you using bootstrap modal for dialog or any other?